# How do you determine the signature of a boost::function type?

Tags: function, boost

How can I determine the signature of boost::function?

In boost::signals2 there is a **boost::signals2::signature_type** type, but in boost::function - there isn't.

Example: http://liveworkspace.org/code/727a1e51cb829bab743d922bd7f1b03a

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boost::function<...>::result_type` and `boost::function<...>::arg1_type`, `boost::function<...>::arg2_type` etc...

See the [reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html).

If you want the whole thing as a function-type, you can use the synthesizing features in Boost.FunctionTypes.

Comment: Then it is better this way: http://liveworkspace.org/code/93d8f554c64f822b0336e803edd5d6b7

Comment: You can do that even without inheritance or any runtime-changes:(specialize a template on function<T> and extract T). The reason why I didn't post that was that it doesn't work with 'old-style' boost::function like `boost::function<void,int,float,std::string>`.